# Pass a variable to other function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.header_menu_item').on('mouseenter',function(){
    var default_img = $(this).find('.header_menu_item_icon_img').attr('src');
    var hover_img = $(this).find('.header_menu_item_icon_img').attr('data-hover');
    $(this).find('.header_menu_item_icon_img').prop('src',hover_img);
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).find('.header_menu_item_icon_img').prop('src',default_img);
});
```

How can i pass default_img var to following mouseleave function?
Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2):

One option will be declare a variable outside of the 2 functions.

```
var default_img = '';
$('.header_menu_item').on('mouseenter',function(){
default_img = $(this).find('.header_menu_item_icon_img').attr('src');
   var hover_img = $(this).find('.header_menu_item_icon_img').attr('data-hover');
   $(this).find('.header_menu_item_icon_img').prop('src',hover_img);
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
   $(this).find('.header_menu_item_icon_img').prop('src',default_img);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set it as data on the element itself and then retrieve it later

```
//setting
$(this).data('default_img',default_img);

//retrieving
var img = $(this).data('default_img');
```

Through native js

```
//setting
this.dataset['default_img'] = default_img;

//retrieving
var img = this.dataset['default_img'];
```

You could also before hand set up a data-* attribute on the html itself so no need to use JS to set the initial data

```
<img src="http://example.com/someimg.jpg" data-default_img="http://example.com/someimg.jpg" />
```

[data-* attributes reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)

[dataset reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

[jQuery's data() method](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use global variables. A function can only pass variables directly to functions that it calls, not functions that are called outside.

```
var default_img;
$('.header_menu_item').on('mouseenter',function(){
    default_img = $(this).find('.header_menu_item_icon_img').attr('src');
    var hover_img = $(this).find('.header_menu_item_icon_img').attr('data-hover');
    $(this).find('.header_menu_item_icon_img').prop('src',hover_img);
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).find('.header_menu_item_icon_img').prop('src',default_img);
});
```

Comment: default_img can differ if you enter two $('.header_menu_item') but only leave one of them, you have to store default_img by each header_menu_item

Comment: @ThomasFellinger Unless they're nested, I doubt that can happen.

Comment: i think they just need to be positioned somehow overlapping to get failures

Comment: We need to see the HTML to know whether this is important.

Answer (score -1):

you can not pass it directly - you can store it in an outer variable - but you have to do it by each item:

```
$('.header_menu_item').each(function(){

  var $header_menu_item_icon_img = $(this).find('.header_menu_item_icon_img'),
      default_img = $header_menu_item_icon_img.attr('src'),
      hover_img = $header_menu_item_icon_img.attr('data-hover');

  $(this).on('mouseenter',function(){ 
    $header_menu_item_icon_img.prop('src',hover_img);
  }).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $header_menu_item_icon_img.prop('src',default_img); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Only user wanted to pass `default_img` variable in `mouseleave` function.. why `each` function is needed.. ??

Comment: because default_img can differ per menu_item and can and will be overwritten in a global variable